# Best deduplication strategy to be used with spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-kafka, duplicates, azure-hdinsight

What is the best de-duplication strategy to be used with spark?

- I have a Kafka source that is continuously fed with structured information (say JSON) from various producers continuously.
- I am having an HDInsight spark cluster that can pick messages in real time for this Kafka source, process them and put it into a destination Kafka source in real time.

My use case demands that the information received from the source may have duplicates which need to be eliminated. The duplicates have to be be checked against say last 24 hours.

My attempt :

1. I tried using the .dropduplicate method in spark along with watermarking , but I think it's not the best thing to do since the data for a single day window may exceed 50 GB in my use case.
2. I also looked for bloom filter implementation which can be used with spark but couldn't find a good one.

My question:

1. What are the possible approaches to eliminate duplication in general for large scale spark streaming application.?
2. Which of these features can be used along with HDInsight clusters on Azure ?
3. What are the fault tolerance capability in such services ?

Comment: Have you tried using a lookup table where the trick is to partition the table on the right columns which can help in identifying the duplicated without the right partitions it would take longer time to find if row is duplicate or not

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the same @siddharthajain ?

Comment: I have taken following approach on de duplication of streaming data, for me the time frame of deduplicate of data was 12 hours and I had certain id's, combination of which distributes the data very well so I created partitioned folder such like id1 then inside it is id2 then id3 and till 5 levels so when the streaming data comes then read is quite fast because data is highly partitioned thus on each partition level the amount of data to be compared record by record is very small thus the lookup time was very less. I hope you get some idea what I am trying to explain

Comment: Yes, I can understand this approach @siddharthajain . Did you make this directory structure simply inside the local disc and did a simple read operation to check for duplicate ? Also, what was the average number of items in each partition ? And did you use this approach on a Azure HDInsight cluster ?

Comment: I made this structure on S3 and spark consumer was in a EMR cluster. It was a simple read in the terms I had created a virtual table over S3 and as soon as new records were coming (I had a batch of 3 seconds on spark consumer) I was passing those 5 id on which I have partitioned data in  the where clause thus highly filtering the data. Size of each partition on highest level was in range 1GB to 6GB but most of the partitions were around of size 2 gb  then there were around 30 such partitions. So in theory with each where clause amount of data to searched got decreased by 10 to 15 times